# R - Merge/Join and only replace if missing (Priority?)

Tags: r, join, replace, merge, missing-data

Is it possible to only merge data for values that are missing?

For example, say I have two datasets.  D1 is my priority dataset, but I want to use information from D2 to fill in any missing data in D1. If D1 and D2 have conflicting values, then I want to keep the values in D1 and discard D2.

```
D1 <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,3),
  x=c("cow",NA,"sheep"))

D2 <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,3),
  x=c("cow","turtle","parrot"))
```

Ideally, the final dataset would look like this:

```
D3 <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,3),
  x=c("cow","turtle","sheep"))
```

`turtle` would replace the `NA`, but `parrot` wouldn't replace `sheep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you may use `match` -

```
inds <- is.na(D1$x)
D1$x[inds] <- D2$x[match(D1$id[inds], D2$id)]
D1

#  id      x
#1  1    cow
#2  2 turtle
#3  3  sheep
```

Answer (score 2):

If the rows are uniquely identified you can use `dplyr::rows_patch()`.

```
library(dplyr)
  
D1 %>%
  rows_patch(D2, by = "id")

  id      x
1  1    cow
2  2 turtle
3  3  sheep
```

Comment: I'm getting an unspecified error with this: `Error: Attempting to patch missing rows.`.  However, the `match` function worked.  I think that `rows_patch()` fails when there are more rows (IDs) in Y than X.  I'm going to submit a bug report.

Comment: I just saw the following documentation for the function "key values in y must occur in x". Thus, `match` from base R is a better solution because it does not have the same requirement.